# Spark filtering with regex

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to filter file data into good and bad data per the date, hence will get 2 result files. From test file, first 4 lines need to go in good data and last 2 lines in bad data.

I am having 2 issues

1. I am not getting any good data, result file is empty
2. and bad data result looks like following - picking up the name characters only

   (,C,h)
   (,J,u)
   (,T,h)
   (,J,o)
   (,N,e)
   (,B,i)

**Test file**

```
Christopher|Jan 11, 2017|5 
Justin|11 Jan, 2017|5 
Thomas|6/17/2017|5 
John|11-08-2017|5 
Neli|2016|5 
Bilu||5
```

**Load and RDD**

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("test/data.txt")
scala> val fileRDD = file.map(x => x.split("|"))
```

**RegEx**

```
scala> val singleReg = """(\w(3))\s(\d+)(,)\s(\d(4))|(\d+)\s(\w(3))(,)\s(\d(4))|(\d+)(\/)(\d+)(\/)(\d(4))|(\d+)(-)(\d+)(-)(\d(4))""".r
```

Is three " (double quotes) in the beginning and end and .r important here?

**Filter**
issue area

```
scala> val validSingleRecords = fileRDD.filter(x => (singleReg.pattern.matcher(x(1)).matches))
scala> val badSingleRecords = fileRDD.filter(x => !(singleReg.pattern.matcher(x(1)).matches))
```

**Turn array into string**

```
scala> val validSingle = validSingleRecords.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2)))
scala> val badSingle = badSingleRecords.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2)))
```

**Write file**

```
scala> validSingle.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("data/singValid")
scala> badSingle.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("data/singBad")
```

**Update 1**
My regex above was wrong, i have updated it as. in scala backslash is a escape character, so need to duplicate

```
val singleReg = """\\w{3}\\s\\d+,\\s\\d{4}|\\d+\\s\\w{3},\\s\\d{4}|\\d+\/\\d+\/\\d{4}|\\d+-\\d+-\\d{4}""".r
```

Checked the regex on regex101 and the dates in the first 4 lines pass.

I have run the the test again and i am still getting the same result.

Comment: Can you please mention the expected output for good and bad data?

Comment: First 4 lines need to go in good data and the last 2 lines in bad data, per the regex.

Comment: Why do you think that your REGEX matches the first 4 lines?  What do you think does `\w(3)`? The number of occurrences is for sure not 3 without curly braces. Your's literally matches the `3` You can test the REGEX online, e.g. here https://regex101.com/

Comment: I have updated the regex, testing... will update shortly

Comment: Added update 1 to the question

Comment: Anyone have the Python version of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code:

1. The character that you are using to split the lines of `data.txt` is wrong. It should be `'|'` instead of `"|"`.
2. The regex `singleReg` is wrong.

The correct code is as follows:

**Load and RDD**

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("test/data.txt")
scala> val fileRDD = file.map(x => x.split('|'))
```

**RegEx**

```
scala> val singleReg = """\w{3}\s\d{2},\s\d{4}|\d{2}\s\w{3},\s\d{4}|\d{1}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}""".r
```

**Filter**

```
scala> val validSingleRecords = fileRDD.filter(x => (singleReg.pattern.matcher(x(1)).matches))
scala> val badSingleRecords = fileRDD.filter(x => !(singleReg.pattern.matcher(x(1)).matches))
```

**Turn array into string**

```
scala> val validSingle = validSingleRecords.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2)))
scala> val badSingle = badSingleRecords.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2)))
```

**Write file**

```
scala> validSingle.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("data/singValid")
scala> badSingle.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("data/singBad")
```

The above code will give you following output -

**data/singValid**

```
(Christopher,Jan 11, 2017,5 )
(Justin,11 Jan, 2017,5 )
(Thomas,6/17/2017,5 )
(John,11-08-2017,5 )
```

**data/singBad**

```
(Neli,2016,5 )
(Bilu,,5)
```

Comment: With splitting on comma or space we use "," or " ", why with pipe we are using single quote as '|'?

Comment: The answer to your query is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867743/scala-splitting-with-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes