# Scala: Splitting with Double Quotes ("") vs Single Quotes ('')

Tags: scala

I am splitting a String in Scala with Comma using Double Quotes, like this:

```
scala> val a = "a,b,c"
a: String = a,b,c

scala> a.split(",")
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

It is working fine. Also, it works fine when using Single Quotes:

```
scala> a.split(',')
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

But, when I split the String with Pipe using Double Quotes, it doesn't give correct result:

```
scala> val a = "a|b|c"
a: String = a|b|c

scala> a.split("|")
res3: Array[String] = Array(a, |, b, |, c)
```

Whereas, using Single Quotes gives correct result:

```
scala> a.split('|')
res2: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

Can anyone help me in understanding this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `'|'` is `Char` whereas `"|"` is `String`.

```
scala> val a1 = '|'
// a1: Char = |

scala> val a2 = "|"
// a2: String = |
```

Now, when you pass a `String` to `String.split` it uses it to create a a regular expression, which is then used to split the `String`.

And `|` is a special character in regular expressions.

Which means that you need to `escape` your `|` so that it will not be considered as a special character. In regular expressions, we use `\` to mark the next character as `escaped`.

```
scala> val a = "a|b|c"
// a: String = a|b|c

scala> a.split(raw"\|")
// res2: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)


scala>a.split("\\|")
// res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

Or,

```
scala> val a = "a|b|c"
// a: String = a|b|c

scala> val regex = raw"\|".r
// regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = \|

scala> regex.split(a)
// res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

Notice that `\\|` and `\|` difference when not using `raw`, that is because `\` is a special character in Scala `Strings`.

So when we are not using `raw` `String` we have to first tell that the next `\` is not a special character and will not be processed by `String`, hence left as it is. So the processed `String` will look like `\|`.

Answer (score 2):

The split method is overloaded. If you use single quote `'` you are splitting by a character:

```
def split(separator: Char)
```

If you use double quote `"` you are using java split that takes a regex:

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Since pipe `|` is a reserved character in a regex you need to escape it if you are using double quotes:

```
a.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Split by char or escape if you string by string.

Use it as char

```
scala> a.split('|')
res5: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

It works, you need to use escape sequence. Pipe (|) has a special meaning. You need to use escape sequence to say its a normal char.

```
scala> val a = "a|b|c"
a: String = a|b|c

scala> a.split("\\|")
res2: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

with triple quotes

```
scala> a.split("""\|""")
res4: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe (|) is a metacharacter in regex. You'd need to escape it:

```
scala> a.split("\\|")
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```